# How to numerically sort a list to be a sequence in python?

Tags: python

Let's say you had a list like:

`list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]`

but you wanted to format it to follow a `[1, 3, 7, 9]` format like:

`list = [1, 3, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1]`

Adding each number into its index position (i.e., 3 is always added after 1, if 1 exists, otherwise it's added after 9 if it exists and so on]

Also you don't know what numbers will be added into the list. It could be different every time, so you cannot set hard variables for each number and position them that way.

Pseudo code below because I really am unsure how to handle this

```
list_position = 0
for i, x in enumerate(list):
  if i == 0:
    list.insert(list_position, i)
    list_position += 1
  else:
    list_position = list_position + list_position
    list.insert(list_position, i)
```

Comment: Quick tip, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, as it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]
count = {}
final = []

for num in mylist:
    if num in count:
        count[num] += 1
    else:
        count[num] = 1

while not all(value == 0 for value in count.values()):
    for key in count.keys():
        if count[key] > 0:
            final.append(key)
            count[key] -= 1

print(final == [1, 3, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1])
```

At the end, I just printed if my output was the same as the list you provided, which printed out `True`.

I first counted everything in `mylist` in the `count` dictionary. I then iterated through the keys in the dictionary. Since the keys in a python dictionary [are ordered](https://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2020/02/05/dicts-ordered/) we don't have to worry about sorting the keys. We iterate through the keys, decrementing the count once we append them to final. The `while` loop is exited when all values in `count` are equal to 0. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use counter and decrement from dictionary

```
from collections import Counter
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]
d = Counter(lst)
res = []
while d:
    l = d.keys()
    res.extend(l)
    d = {k: d[k]-1 for k in l if d[k]}
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my approach where I think I differ from other solutions is just mine is a little bit generic where all the elements in the format list don't have to be in the list that needs to be sorted and vice versa

```
myList = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 4]

formatList = [1, 3, 7, 9, 10]

countList = [myList.count(i) for i in formatList]
output = []
while True:
    for i in range(len(formatList)):
        if countList[i] > 0:
            output.append(formatList[i])
            countList[i] -= 1
            myList.remove(formatList[i])
    if sum(countList) == 0:
        break

output += myList
print(output)
```

this code will append everything that is out of the pattern specified at the end of the list

```
[1, 3, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score -2):

The variable `b` is your expected output.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9]
b = []

reference = sorted(list(set(a)))

while len(a) > 0:
    for ref in reference:
        if ref in a:
            b.append(ref)
            a.pop(a.index(ref))
```